# Why do excluding NULL results in a SQL query cause a drag on performance, and how can I best resolve the problem?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am building a SQL query to be used for data analysis. The query includes a `LEFT JOIN` from a `CoachingEvent` table to an `Organization` table that contains recipient `Organization` data, and a `LEFT JOIN` from an `Organization` table to a `Region` table used for geographical analysis of data.

It is possible and valid for a `CoachingEvent` to link to no `Organizations`, and for an `Organization` to link to no `Region`.

The query needs to return at least one record for EVERY `CoachingEvent` regardless of whether it is linked to an org or a region, and the query must allow the user to filter by region, including a filter for "No Region Assigned"

The SQL statement we are using to query the data can be simplified as follows:

```
SELECT 
    CoachingEvent.*, 
    Organization.OrgID, Organization.OrgName, 
    Region.RegionID, Region.RegionName
FROM 
    CoachingEvent
LEFT JOIN 
    Organization ON Organization.OrgID = CoachingEvent.OrgID
LEFT JOIN 
    Region ON Region.RegionID = Organization.RegionID
WHERE
    CoachingEvent.StartDate BETWEEN '01/01/2023' AND '03/31/2023'
    AND ISNULL(Region.RegionID, -1) IN ([RegionList])
```

For clarity on the amount of data, the `CoachingEvent` table contains about 100,000 rows, and this query returns about 5,000 rows in less than 1 second when all `RegionID`s (including `RegionID` -1) are included in the `[RegionList]`.

It runs just as quickly if we change the `Region` selection criteria to

```
AND (Region.RegionID IS NULL OR Region.RegionID IN (@RegionList))
```

However, if we exclude NULL values from the selection criteria by excluding -1 from the `[RegionList]`, the query is taking a factor of 10X longer to run.

For example, if we use

```
AND ISNULL(Region.RegionID, -1) IN (3)
```

or

```
AND Region.RegionID IN (3)
```

we find either statement causes the query to take 25 seconds to return 699 rows.

For comparison purposes, the following statement

```
AND ISNULL(Region.RegionID, -1) IN (-1, 3)
```

returns 712 rows in less than 1 second.

Hopefully this describes our dilemma. We are struggling to find a way to resolve this problem, as our users need the ability to filter data based on specific regions and/or all regions including events with no region assigned.

**IN SUMMARY**: the query only runs within expected timeframes if we include `NULL` values in the results, or if we change the `JOIN` to the `Region` table from a `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`, but that defeats the purpose of reporting on `CoachingEvents` with no assigned `Organization` or `Region`.

Comment: The _actual execution plan_ is often a good starting point for analyzing query performance issues. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: apart from the execution plan, by looking at the 'WHERE' clause you have for comparing the RegionID from the Region table, dont see any reason for not make the join as `INNER JOIN`, the condition search from the right table (region) only make sense when you have the result found (inner join) unless you have -1 from the search list?

Comment: Either a LEFT JOIN *with* filter including NULLs, or an INNER JOIN without inclusion of NULLS makes sense. A LEFT JOIN not including nulls is just an implicit INNER JOIN, and an INNER JOIN with inclusion of NULLS will return no NULLs since it's part of the join criteria. That doesn't answer your question, but it seems like maybe you are confused on that part.

Comment: Whenever I see date predicates using BETWEEN I feel obligated to post this. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common Also, when using date literals they should always be in the format YYYYMMDD. Any other format can get the dates wrong based on various settings between the database and the connection.